# vscode で kill ring はありますか

Tags: vscode

emacs では、 kill ring があり、過去の文字列のカット(切り取り)を n 個まで保持していて、貼り付けの際はその中から貼り付けたい文字列を選択することができます。

#### 質問

- vscode において、このような kill ring の機能はありますか？

  - 参考までに、自分は今 vim keybinding で作業しています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio Codeの標準機能の範囲内では、いわゆるkill ring相当の機能はないようです。

しかし、英語版Stack Overflowを参照すると、Visual Studio Codeの拡張機能として提供されているEmacs Keymap Improvedがまさしくその機能を有しているようです。

> Proper kill-ring: the support for kill-rings in hiro-sun's was inconsistent with the original emacs spec for the kill-ring. **The kill-ring implemented in my extensnion can store the last 60 kills added to the ring. Yank-pop is also fully supported.**
>   [Emacs Keymap Improved - Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rkwan94.vscode-emacs-improved)

[key bindings - Emacs-like kill ring in visual studio code - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47750778/emacs-like-kill-ring-in-visual-studio-code)

ただし、この拡張機能がVim keybindingとは衝突するかもしれません。